# Minimizing server load in case of many XMLHttpRequest calls

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am making a website where users are to like some articles. Whenever
the like button is clicked I am sending a XMLHttpRequest to the server
to run a file called like_clicked.php along with the get data of
article id and user id. This file takes article id and user id and
updates the sql database and also adds a node in an xml file related
to the user. This is the first time I am doing something for mass
usage.

I am worried about the server load when too many users call the like_clicked.php file. Please help me, if this method is ok.

I am also thinking of an alternative in case the above method fails. I
am thinking of making many like_clicked files (namely
like_clicked1.php, like_clicked2.php ... ) to minimize load on a
single i-node. Is there a method to detect that it is better to call
the next like_clicked file. Here we would need to detect how many
calls per unit time are coming for the particular file. How do we
handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what you're asking is it better to point all requests to be handled by 1 file or is it better if it's handled by multitude of files that share the similar name? It's unclear what you're aiming at. If you build something for mass usage, you can't run it on 1 server unless it's a freaking powerhouse of a machine.

Comment: inode maybe thought of as file in present reference.

Comment: Ya, i am thinking of using multiple files with similar name, but for that also I will have to check using a particular file or a particular function. When multiple calls are made to the same file or the function, it will take time to handle all of them one by one. I am looking for a way in which this congestion may be minimized.

Comment: Your bottleneck won't be the request of the file, it'll be the database operation, especially because you're writing to the database. So no, it doesn't make sense to split your requests on several files that are doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have those files on one server - than there is no any difference. And as far as I can see, it there should be no heavy computations in those files. If it will appear to be slow - check if you can imporve database request. Once you have really a lot of users you will need to put few servers and some load balancer which will call different servers. Making files with different names makes no sence at all.

> When multiple calls are made to the same file or the function, it will
>   take time to handle all of them one by one.

This is nonsence untill we are not talking about same session (if session is a default PHP session). It will not execute requests one by one if sessions are different (read - users are different). PHP can easily handle simultaneous requests to the same PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating code is probably the worse thing you can try:

- You create yourself a maintenance nightmare.
- You reduce the effect of all caching levels you might benefit from: memory, file system, FastCGI, PHP bytecode cache (if you have one)...

Even if the concept of cache did not exist, you'd just make the disk spin up and down to read from different locations ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple files to do the same thing is not a solution and as was already stated in another answer, it would be a maintenance nightmare to maintain.

In programming, get your code working first then worry about optimizing later after you're able to see actual results on how your application runs. One piece of advice for your `like_click.php` page: **Do as little as possible.**

Later on, if you discover that things are slowing down you may have to research ways to cluster your website into multiple servers to spread the load across different hardware and networks. This is very common for any large scale website.